# Mootools slideshow adapting

Tags: javascript, mootools, slideshow

I'm looking for a Mootools slideshow that changes main picture with a timer (normal slideshow function) and has a clickable thumbnail list. Because I have many other mootools features in the site I am working so the slideshow has to be mootools.

I found two options:

- [scrollgallery2.mashitup.de](http://scrollgallery2.mashitup.de/) (which is a v.2 of [this](http://mootools.net/forge/p/scrollgallery)) - how to make it start the slideshow? (its stoped in the first picture)
- [github.com/jakobholmelund/SpinSlider](https://github.com/jakobholmelund/SpinSlider#readme) (which Jakob adapted from a jQuery slideshow) - the .js file is missing the thumbs code. Any ideas how to merge/translate the jQuery idea to Mootools?
  (see under)

jQuery version:

```
if (options.bulletThumbs) {
var thumbName = slides.eq(i).data('thumb');
if (thumbName) {
    var liMarkup = $('<li class="has-thumb">' + i + '</li>')
    liMarkup.css({
        "background": "url(" + options.bulletThumbLocation + thumbName + ") no-repeat"
    });
}
}

orbitWrapper.children('ul.orbit-bullets').append(liMarkup);
liMarkup.data('index', i);
liMarkup.click(function () {
stopClock();
shift($(this).data('index'));
});
}
setActiveBullet();
}
```

Mootools adapted by Jakob Holmelund:

```
if(this.options.bullets){
        this.bullets = new Element("ul").addClass("spin-bullets").inject(this.spinWrap);
        this.slides.each(function(slide, index){
            new Element("li",{text:index+1}).addEvent("click", function(){
                self._stopClock();
                self._spin(index);
            }).inject(self.bullets);
        });
        this._setActiveBullet();
    }
```

Any suggestions how to fix one of this? or any other slideshow idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is new code I added on the `.js` of [Jakobs](https://github.com/jakobholmelund/SpinSlider#readme) file. Maybe good for a next version of that slideshow.

In the JS file:
 ( this adds the capacity to see if a `img` is in the slide and adds thumbnail to the `<li>` CSS background-image)

```
if(this.options.bullets){
        this.bullets = new Element("ul").addClass("spin-bullets").inject(this.spinWrap);
        this.slides.each(function(slide, index){
            var stl = '';
            if (!slide.hasChildNodes()) stl = 'background-image: url('+slide.getAttribute('src')+')';
            else if (slide.getChildren('img').length > 0) stl = 'background-image: url('+slide.getChildren('img')[0].get('src')+')'; 
            else if (slide.get('img')) stl = 'background-image: url('+slide.get('img').get('src')+')'; 

            new Element("li",{text:index+1, style: stl, class: ((stl != '')?"spin-bullets-img":"")}).addEvent("click", function(){
                self._stopClock();
                self._spin(index);
            }).inject(self.bullets);
        });
        this._setActiveBullet();
    }
```

Then add in the CSS:

```
.spin-bullets li.spin-bullets-img { 
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
background-position: center top;
background-size: 80px auto;
border:#CCC 4px solid;
}
.spin-bullets li.spin-bullets-img.active {
border:#88F 4px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel it may be easier to use something that already exists. I took a quick look in the MooTools forge (http://mootools.net/forge/browse?search=gallery) and found the following:

http://software.bmo-design.de/scrollgallery.html

I modified the very awesome http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/ on this project awhile back: http://treecareenterprises.com/c/tree-care-photo-gallery/?showonly=5

Unfortunately I do not have time to extract the code today but feel free to take a look and see if you can grab the relevant tidbits. Also it looks like it is running on v1.2.4 you may want to upgrade it to 1.4 which is not as hard as it may seem see the following link for guidence: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Upgrade-from-1.2-to-1.3-or-1.4

Comment: Thank you for checking my problem Tim. Your suggestion is the same as my first option. That gallery does not change the first image. Its static. No slideshow function. Do you know how to "start" it?

Comment: Hmmmm sorry didn't notice it was the same. See edited answer.

Comment: No problem. Tim, that gallery does not change the first image. Its static. No slideshow function. Do you know how to "start" it?

Comment: Yes you would basically use setTimeout and trigger the click event on the next thumbnail. If the loop counter is > array length go back to the first thumbnail. Or see edit.

Comment: Thank you again for taking a look into this. Your suggestion used mootools 1.2 and I needed 1.3 so I re-wrote the other options JS file.

Comment: By the way, in case you also need. Live version [here](http://www.sofiesrenting.com/v2/dependent/SpinSlider-master/SpinSlider-master/index.html), for some days.